# Listar datos en campo separados por , (coma)

Tags: php, mysql

Hay una forma de poder ver la información almacenada en un campo (en este caso framework ), separado por ',' como una lista separada ? en celdas separadas

Por ejemplo:

[image: 1 Laravel 2 Laravel 2 Symfony 2 Codeigniter]

Esta es la tabla con los datos en el mismo campo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es decir que cada dato este en una celda?

Comment: Es un poco complicado dar una solución a tu problema, tal vez por lo difícil que seria llegar a la respuesta, o tal vez porque lo que pides implica no darle una correcta solución a lo que rompe de forma explicita la 1ra forma normal. Mas allá de la solución, **y si es posible**, te recomiendo lo normalices.

Comment: En sql server esta la función string_split, no se si mysql tendrá un equivalente

Comment: Desde php es realmente sencillo hacerlo, tan solo necesitas usar la función `explode()` y separar el array por comas. A partir de ahí ya te montas la vista como tú quieres. Igualmente, te recomiendo que lo intentes hacer primero... venir aquí a preguntar "esto se puede hacer" o "cómo hago esto" sin haberlo intentado queda muy feo y no nos motiva para ayudarte... si tú mismo no inviertes tiempo en tu problema, por qué habríamos de hacerlo nosotros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo tanto con MySQL como con PHP. Para hacerlo con MySQL puedes probar a utilizar `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Este sería un ejemplo:

```
SELECT id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(framework SEPARATOR ',')
FROM frameworks
GROUP BY id;
```

Si quieres evitar duplicidades, añade `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT framework SEPARATOR ',')
FROM frameworks
GROUP BY id;
```

Para hacerlo con PHP puedes utilizar un bucle para agrupar los frameworks con el mismo id y luego `implode()` para unirlos:

```
$groupedFw = [];

foreach ($frameworks as $framework) {
    $groupedFw[$framework['id']][] = $framework['framework'];
}

echo "<table><tr><td>id</td><td>framework</td></tr>";
foreach ($groupedFw as $id => $groupFw) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $id . "</td><td>" . implode(',', $groupFw) . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```